# How to select iOS simulator as destination if no option is available?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I downloaded a project and execute it  in my xcode, it have ios device by default in run device selected and have no other option, so xcode complained saying no ios devices are avilabale .... slect ios simulator.

Comment: Have you downloaded SDK?

Comment: I guess Xcode in your mac is not lastest version, so there are no iOS 7.1 simulator and Deployment Target of the project is set 7.1.

Comment: yes, i have download comlete project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **XCode > Preferences > Downloads.**

And download simulator

[image]

And then when you open XCode, left side top you can select iOS simulator rather than your device.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou mam, Can you suggest me a link for reusable uitableviewcell example. some thing like prototype which can be used in all .storyboard file for designing purpose

Comment: Try to goole first. If you are still getting error, you can post here.     https://www.google.co.in/search?q=reusable+uitableviewcell+example&oq=reusable+uitableviewcell+example&aqs=chrome..69i57.269j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Comment: i think .storyboard does not support reusiblity, how to implement it if required.

Comment: If you are not comfortable with storyboard, you can use XIBs.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, it is fixed when I select Deployment Target(General, Deployment Info) from 8.2 to 8.1(drop to a version that I have).